# Oracle 12.1 OCI_ATTR_UB8_ROW_COUNT

Tags: oracle

> Received ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [qerrmOFBu1],
>   [3148], [ORA-03148: OCI_ATTR_ROW_COUNT cannot return a row count
>   exceeding UB4MAXVAL. Resolution online is to Upgrade Oracle client to
>   version 12 client libraries or higher and use OCI_ATTR_UB8_ROW_COUNT
>   instead.

I upgraded the client version but the batch is still receiving the same error. How do I change the batch to use the new Attribute OCI_ATTR_UB8_ROW_COUNT.